# How to get an array object from an element inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this PHP code which I'm stuck at. I need to get the array result of the `"query" => array`. For now, when I run the code, I will get the result of a  `"query" => array`, but as an attribute and not an actual array.

```
$input = array(
    "area"=>"problems",
    "sub_area"=>"find",
    "method"=>"post",

    // *** THIS LINE ***
    "query"=>array(
        "component"=>array("name"=>"Name1", "version"=>"Vb"),
    )
);
try {
    $output = $web_service->query($input);
    if($output['HTTP_OK'] == true) {
        print_r($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually have 3 levels of arrays here.  To see what I mean, try this `print $input["query"]["component"]["name"];`

Comment: Show us what you are trying to achieve as the `$input` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly, what do you mean?

Comment: @RiggsFolly which part that is confusing? :P I will explain it

Comment: @dana I see what you mean. Any suggestion that you could think of to get the results of "query"=>array( "component"=>array("name"=>"Name1", "version"=>"Vb") only?

Comment: Your array looks fine. So what are you saying is wrong with it. Show us an example of what you want it to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

```
try {
    $output = $web_service->query($input);
    if($output['HTTP_OK'] == true) {
        // print_r($output['DATA']);
        foreach (json_decode($output['DATA']) as $obj) {
            print_r($obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks guys!